# what does the pd.read.csv in python turn your data to

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have used pandas to read the csv file already

i have some questions, is the csv file been set to be some sort of list, or do i have to store the data?
i used df = pd.read.cv bla2

Comment: It reads the csv and converts it into a pandas dataframe

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2):

Your `df` would be a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object that includes all of the data.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned the data will be loaded as a `DataFrame`. I believe the correct syntax you are after is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```